# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtWebEngineWidgets': No such file or directory

Tags: qt

used this `QT += webenginewidgets` in its associated pro files. But still getting the error of  fatal error

> C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtWebEngineWidgets': No such file or
>   directory

I am trying to include the following file in one header file

```
   #include <QtWebEngineWidgets>
```

Comment: Do you have this file in your Qt installation folder?

Comment: If so, try `#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets>`

Comment: Have you checked for that module to be installed? By default it is not installed.

Comment: @VladimirBershov It detected the path #include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets>

But after further build it gives following error
D:\Qt\Qt5.6.2\5.6\msvc2015\include\QtWebEngineWidgets\qwebenginefullscreenrequest.h:40: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h': No such file or directory

Comment: I am able to build using following includes
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h>
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets>

Answer (score 0):

here is some example provided by Qt.

[WebBrowser Exemple](https://doc.qt.io/QtWebBrowser/)
[WebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-overview.html#qt-webengine)

```
#include <QWebEngineView>
QT += webenginewidgets
```

Comment: I am able to build using following includes

`#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h>`
  #include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets> – Manish Karma 37 secs ago    Edit   Delete